# How to create images with a low file size in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ppi, dpi

I need to create an image screen with a low file size. I'm using Photoshop with a 72 dpi, and 300dpi for designing.

My problem is that the entire size of the image increased when I went to save my design. Is it possible to decrease it with these details (72dpi / 300dpi)?

Comment: What are you currently doing to export your image? Which format are you using? Can you provide an example image?

Comment: Using PNG format,mobile suports that only.

Comment: are you using file->save for web already? what filesize do you need to get it to?

Comment: If your output is to be 72ppi, why are you working at 300ppi?

Comment: PPI is irrelevant if you are exporting for screens.

Comment: Also, for PNGs, you probably want to do some post-processing compression after using PhotoShop. There are several options out there for that.

Comment: Is there any tool for compress the image.?

Comment: @MohanRaj, [PNGGauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/) is a good one for Windows, there are links for programs on other operating systems at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @john thank you very much, but some times im using mac too, that software availble for mac?

Comment: @MohanRaj, I haven't used it, but [http://imageoptim.com/](http://imageoptim.com/) appears have the same functionality.

Comment: I'll second imageoptim

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using File > **Save For Web & Devices**

The Save For Web option in Photoshop strips away all of the extra info in the images to make them as small as possible. In most cases, unless you need transparency, I would use JPG around 70-90 Quality. There isn't too much of a difference there. PNGs are nice for crisp & transparent pictures, but tend to have larger file sizes than JPGs.

Comment: Just wanted to add that PNG's will look better for graphics-only stuff while JPG's usually look better for  photo-heavy files. With that said, if quality isn't the main concern then JPG's are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, try [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) to shrink your images further. I've gotten good results from it even with images that are already saved for web.